# Problems with displaying .txt file (delimiters)

Tags: r

I have a problem with one task where I have to load some data set, and I have to make sure that missing values are read in properly and that column names are unambiguous.

The format of .txt file:

[image: Format]

At the end, data set should contain only country column and median age.
I tried using read.delim, precisely this chunk:

```
rawdata <- read.delim("rawdata_343.txt", sep = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```

And when I run it, I get this:

[image: Result]

It confuses me that if country has multiple words (Turks and Caicos Islands) it assigns every word to another column.

Since I am still a beginner in R, any suggestion would be very helpful for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Three points to note about your input file: (1) the first two lines at the top are not tabular and should be skipped with `skip = 2`, (2) your column separators are tabs and this should be specified with `sep = "\t"`, and (c) you have no headers, so `header = FALSE`.  Your command should be: -

`rawdata <- read.delim("rawdata_343.txt", sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = FALSE, skip = 2)`

UPDATE: A fourth point is that the first column includes row numbers, so `row.names = 1`.  This also addresses the follow-up comment.

`rawdata <- read.delim("rawdata_343.txt", sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = FALSE, skip = 2, row.names = 1)`

Comment: Now it is a lot better, however I still should get 2 columns (Country, Median age) so the final format should be, for example, Monaco, 55.4. Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: If you need to drop the first column (with numbers) you can run `rawdata <- rawdata[, -1]`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your delimiter that you are specifying in the `sep=` argument is telling R to consider *spaces* as the column delimiter. Looking at your data as a .txt file, there is no apparent delimiter (like commas that you would find in a typical .csv). If you can put the data in a tabular form in something like a .csv or .xlsx file, R is much better at reading that data as expected. As it is, you may struggle to get the .txt format to read in a tabular fashion, which is what I assume you want.

P.s. you can use `read.csv()` if you do end up putting the data in that format.